# How to open existing powerpoint and paste an excel range

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to create a macro which opens an existing powerpoint template for me, copy data from a certain sheet of excel and then paste it in a specific slide in powerpoint.

I tried googling it online and created something but it doesnt work. The macro runs but I do not see any output. Please help. Below is the code I am working on:

```
Sub Excelrangetopowerpoint()

Dim rng As Range
Dim Powerpointapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Application
Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim myShape As Object
Dim myslide As Object


Set rng = Worksheets("regions").Range("B1:N18")

On Error Resume Next

Set Powerpointapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")
DestinationPPT = ("C:\Users\OLX-Admin\Dropbox (Corporate Finance)\Naspers Monthly Reporting\Prep for call\From teams\FY2019\OLX Group Monthly Report_Sep'18_Macro.pptx")
Powerpointapp.Presentations.Open (DestinationPPT)


If Err.Number = 429 Then
MsgBox "Powerpoint could not be found.aborting."
Exit Sub

On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

rng.Copy

Set myslide = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(4)

myslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
Set myShape = myslide.Shapes(myslide.Shapes.Count)

myShape.Left = 152
myShape.Top = 152

Powerpointapp.Visible = True
Powerpointapp.Activate

activation.CutCopyMode = False

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
There were some missing parts of your modified code.

Notice that if the presentation is already open, this code will open the existing file in "read-only" mode... (so it doesn't care if powerpoint file is already opened or not).

**VBA Code**

```
Sub Excelrangetopowerpoint()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Powerpointapp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim myShape As Object
Dim mySlide As Object

'Copy Range from Excel
Set rng = Worksheets("regions").Range("B1:N18")

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
On Error Resume Next

'Set your destination path for the powerpoint presentation and open the file
Set Powerpointapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")
DestinationPPT = ("C:\Test\My Powerpoint\Presentation1.pptx")
Powerpointapp.Presentations.Open (DestinationPPT)

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "Powerpoint could not be found.aborting."
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set my current Powerpoint window as activated
Set myPresentation = Powerpointapp.ActivePresentation

'Set which slide to paste into
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(4)

'Copy Excel Range
rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position:
myShape.Left = 152
myShape.Top = 152

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
Powerpointapp.Visible = True
Powerpointapp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Source: The code is a combination of the work by Chris Newman: "[Copy & Paste An Excel Range Into PowerPoint With VBA](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba)" & "[Copy & Paste Multiple Excel Ranges To Separate PowerPoint Slides With VBA](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/30/copy-paste-multiple-excel-ranges-to-separate-powerpoint-slides-with-vba)" but with the modification that you add a path to an already existing PowerPoint file.

Comment: Hi Thanks a ton! but I am getting the "Object required" error when I run this macro. Why is that?

Comment: Where do you get the error? At which variable/line? (don't forget to change path to powerpoint file and also have both the powerpoint file and excel file in the same folder :) ). Could help a lot if you share a picture of how you modified the code, if you don't mind.

Comment: Hi, yes yes I changed the path and saved in the same folder, still getting the same error. Also I would live to share the screenshot but I dont know how to share the pic. Dont see any option here to upload pictures. Can you tell me that also pleasee? :) :)

Comment: you can edit your post and add the picture by clicking the [little picture icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6StE.png). I always test my code so I'm so puzzled why it doesn't work,  [you can see it here how I test it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXujd.gif)...

Comment: Hi, I have added the screenshot below, in the answer. is it visible to you?

Comment: It is not showing me any specific error in a line but an overall error, when I run the macro. screenshot is in the answer below.

Comment: The error is "Run time error '424': object required.

Comment: ok I found out the problem, I actually wrote the code again which you sent me. but forgot to add the powerpoint 16 reference from tools. but now I am getting a diff error, which says "powerpoint could not be found.aborting". what am I missing now?

Comment: Good you pass the problem with Run Time Error 424. My setup is of library reference is, maybe it can help: [Library reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbpQS.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/QbpQS.png). The new error message is "Run Time Error 429", something seems to be strange with your setup... Can be some corrupt files or similar. Does Powerpoint start for you?

Comment: When I give the same path in Run, powerpoint opens very easily. but not when I run the macro.

Comment: See below I have posted the pictutre in below answer. the new error that I see if I remove the if condition is "activeX component cant create object"

Comment: you know what I have raised so many questions on this and asked so many people. but you are a genius. such a small mistake and but everyone gave up. Cant thank you much. Have a wonderful day and let people know how impactful you were today. thanks a ton once again buddy.

Answer (score 0):

you were getting that error because of the below line.
Set myslide = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(4)

The correct code is
Set myslide = PowerPointapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(4)